# Using tkinter entries as variables for SQLite

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite

I am relatively new to coding (this is only the second thing I have ever written) and have hit a roadblock.  Any advice, even if it is just a fundamental idea that has evaded me would be helpful.

The actual form I am creating is fairly large (could have up to 400 entry widgets at a future date) so I will place a smaller version of what I am working on here.

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
import time
import datetime

master = Tk()
master.wm_title("Form")

Label(master, text="Cage ID", width=25).grid(column=1, row=1)
d1 = Entry(master)
d1.grid(column=2, row=1)
Label(master, text="Status", width=25).grid(column=1, row=2)
d2 = Entry(master)
d2.grid(column=2, row=2)

def commit_to_database():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("SGAF_Application_Database.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS StatusTable(ID BLOB, Status BLOB, Timestamp TEXT)")#table format

    unix = time.time()
    time_data = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unix).strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S"))#timestamp generation

    c.execute("INSERT INTO StatusTable(ID, Status, Timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
          (d1.get(), d2.get(), time_data))

    conn.commit()

b1 = Button(master, text="Quit", font="bold", fg="black", bg="white", width=15, command=master.quit)
b1.grid(column=3, row=22)

b2 = Button(master, text="Commit", font="bold", fg="black", bg="white", width=15, command=commit_to_database())
b2.grid(column=6, row=22)

mainloop()
```

Basically this is an attempt to build in the commit into a button widget so that I can access filled in entry widgets to fill in the table.  As this exists right now the program enters the variables into the table as soon as I press run for the program.  Since the fields are empty to begin with it puts an empty space in the table for the '.get()' variables.  In my last program I built a 'def' function into a button that also used many '.get()' commands and it works perfectly so I have no idea why this is happening.  Pressing the "Commit" button doesn't seem to do anything at the moment.

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
b2 = Button(master, text="Commit", font="bold", fg="black", bg="white", width=15, command=commit_to_database())
```

This calls `commit_to_database()` RIGHT NOW, and uses its return value (which is None) as the value of the `command` option of the button.  You want to leave off the `()`, to pass the function itself as the command (just like the other button you created).

Comment: Thank you so much!  It is a little embarrassing to miss such a detail but I guess it is part of being a beginner.